# Sort or order by to sort List<T>[] c# using Linq

Tags: c#, list, sorting

How to Sort List< T >[] ?

i has list List[] deliverystatus = new List[3];

```
      deliverystatus[0]---> stores name of file
      deliverystatus[1]---> file delivery date
      deliverystatus[2]---> where to delivery
```

i convert list into table and send it by using mail.
i cant change other code is there any way to sort simplylike

```
      List<T>.OrderBy(o => o.x).ToList()....ETC
```

i want sort entire list based on  deliverystatus[2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        var list = new List<string[]>();
        list.Add(new string[] { "1", "zzz", "z" });
        list.Add(new string[] { "1", "aaa", "x" });
        list.Add(new string[] { "1", "b", "y" });
        list.Add(new string[] { "1", "c", "3" });

        var orderedList = list.OrderBy(e => e[2]);
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have list of 3 element arrays and you want to order its items by third component of each array:

```
// assuming List<string[]> allDeliveryStatuses;
var result = allDeliveryStatuses.OrderBy(d => d[2]).ToList();
```

Side note: Using arrays to represent data structure is bad idea (but clearly should not be my call)

Comment: Excellent why cant i get this idea.